# Cant delete on only one single instance of a DBIC object

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, perl-data-structures, dbix-class

I can delete table entries with this code:

```
foreach my $id (@$idarray) { #idarray is an array reference
$c->model('My::DB')->find($id)->delete;
}
```

That above code only works when @$idarray holds more than one value, but it fails when only 1 value is contained. Some ideas guys?

The error when i only delete 1 entry is:

```
Can't use string ("61") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use
```

61 there is just an example. Represents the $id

sample idarray values: `$idarray = [61, 1, 2, 3];`

Comment: what error message are you getting on failure?

Comment: Can't use string ("61")(that 61 is $id) as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use

Comment: Can you also show the input values, this array refernce contains what in case when it contains more than one value.

Comment: it just contains numbers, plain numbers. id numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that value 61 are used as array refernce, that means in case of single value, I think `$idarray` contains only one value, not array refernce, meaning that try to do it like

```
if( ref $idarray eq 'ARRAY') {
    foreach my $id (@$idarray) { #idarray is an array reference
    $c->model('My::DB')->find($id)->delete;
} else{
    $c->model('My::DB')->find( $idarray )->delete;
}
```

Comment: yeah i figure that out by doing var dump on a single value, it wont return an array reference, rather just a single string. But in your answer does `eq 'ARRAY'` also can detect an array reference?

Comment: yes please take a look at ref function.`ref $idarray` will tell you whether its a array ref or not.

Comment: oh missed your 'ref' part

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, fixed it now. :DDDDDDDDDDDD

Answer (score 4):

You can better do this as:

```
$c->model('My::DB')->search({ 'id' => $idarray })->delete_all;
```

DBIx::Class will automatically detect whether you pass in a single value or array ref and do the right thing. This will also generate a single delete statement for your DB which will may more efficient than doing multiple single deletes in your RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks, im gonna try this one